# Grading of Clifford algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, multilinear-algebra, clifford-algebras

Given a vector space $V$ and a quadratic form $q$ on it, we know that the Clifford algebra $Cl(V,q)$ is a graded algebra, which is a property inherited by the Tensor algebra $T(V)$. Unless in the trivial case $q\equiv 0$, $Cl(V,q)\not\cong T(V)$ as algebras, but I've read that the associated graded algebra is isomorphic to $\Lambda(V)$, because the ideal by which $Cl(V,q)$ is constructed involves terms of degree 2. 
Why is the isomorphism true? What does it means the associated graded algebra in terms of Clifford algebra $Cl(V,q)$ and which informations can I get by this?
Thank you all.

Comment: I think it's "grading"...

Comment: The $\mathbb{N}$-grading on $T(V)$ gives you a filtration on $Cl(V, q)$, not a grading. There is an associated $\mathbb{Z}_2$-grading though. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: Probably involves both, since first you separate even and odd terms and then you consider the filtration of both.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4171718/isomorphism-between-exterior-algebra-and-associated-graded-algebra-of-the-cliff/4171867#4171867) answer your question?

Comment: Yes! Not as I axpected, but it does, thank you.